# How do I prevent the counter from incrementing past the height of the element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

I have a web app where I am creating a scrollable element within the page. This is a scrollable element within a scrollable page, which is difficult and irritating for those with touchscreens and smartphone devices. Instead, for smaller devices, I have implemented scrolling buttons. Instead of scrolling with a scroll bar, there will be a "up" and "down" button. How do I keep the counter from incrementing once at the bottom of the element?

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
      <meta name="author" content="Hayden Bradfield"/>
      <style type="text/css">
      button{display:block;}
      div{width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black;overflow:hidden;}
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
      <button id="scrollup">Up</button>
      <div id="container">
       <p>ksmdaksksmd ka sl sla skd ask alk dksas
       kc ds k s cdks cjskc s cks jdcksd jd csc k
       cdskjdnsj  sdkfjks fj sjk jd jf jd ksf dfjks 
       dsjk js jkf k fjkd jks fj dsjf d fk ks jkf 
       jdfsd j dsdk jk fjdk sj fjd fks sd  abcdef</p>
      </div>
      <button id="scrolldown">Down</button>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       var scrollupbut = document.querySelector('#scrollup');
       var scrolldownbut = document.querySelector('#scrolldown');
       var container = document.querySelector('#container');
       
       var counter = 0;
       scrolldownbut.addEventListener('click',function(){
        var addvals = counter += 10;
        container.scrollTop = counter;
        console.log(counter);
       });
       scrollupbut.addEventListener('click',function(){
        if(counter > 0){
        counter -= 10;
        container.scrollTop = counter;
        console.log(counter);
        }
       });
    
      </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the maximum value for scrollTop with `scrollHeight - clientHeight`, and then check to see if that distance has been reached each time the scrollDown button is pressed.

```
const maxScrollTop=container.scrollHeight - container.clientHeight;
if (counter+10<=maxScrollTop) { counter += 10; }
```

Demo:

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 20px !important; bottom: 0 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <meta name="author" content="Hayden Bradfield"/>
        <style type="text/css">
        button{display:block;}
        div#container{width:100px;height:100px;margin:10px;border:1px solid black;overflow:hidden;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="scrollup">Up</button>        
        <div id="container">
            <p>ksmdaksksmd ka sl sla skd ask alk dksas
            kc ds k sk fjdk sj fjd fks sd  abcdef
             ask alk dksas
            kc ds k sk fjdk sj fjd fks sd  ab</p>
        </div>
        <button id="scrolldown">Down</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var scrollupbut = document.querySelector('#scrollup');
            var scrolldownbut = document.querySelector('#scrolldown');
            var container = document.querySelector('#container');

            var counter = 0;
           const maxScrollTop=container.scrollHeight - container.clientHeight;
           
            scrolldownbut.addEventListener('click',function(){
                if (counter+10<=maxScrollTop) { counter += 10; }
                container.scrollTop = counter;
                console.log(counter);
            });
            scrollupbut.addEventListener('click',function(){
                if(counter > 0){
                counter -= 10;
                container.scrollTop = counter;
                console.log(counter);
                }
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```